# Multiprocessing function in python3 starts throwing several Keyerrors while processing a large pandas dataframe after 1200 lines of processing

Tags: django, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm processing pandas dataframes from a csv file having more than 10,000 lines of data and after processing 1200 lines properly, my code randomly starts throwing keyerrors for a few entries and at the same indexes every time, regardless of which entry falls under those indexes.

Here's my code:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target = calc, args = (i, c, df, a, b, file_id, user.pk))
db.connections.close_all()
p.start()  
p.join()
```

That's where the keyerror occurs in calc():

```
df = df.append([[ i, t_data.loc[c.index(i), 'Asset Description'], t_data.loc[c.index(i), 'Asset Value'], (str(key.loc[j, 'Keyword_1']) + ' ' + str(key.loc[j, 'Keyword_2'])), t_data.loc[c.index(i), 'Current Asset Category'], t_data.loc[c.index(i), 'Current Depreciation'], '%.2f' % float((int(t_data.loc[c.index(i), 'Current Depreciation']) * float(t_data.loc[c.index(i), 'Asset Value'])) / 100), key.loc[j, 'Suggested Asset Category'],  key.loc[j, 'Depreciation Rate'], '%.2f' % float((int(key.loc[c.index(i), 'Depreciation Rate']) * float(t_data.loc[c.index(i), 'Asset Value'])) / 100), key.loc[j, 'Probability']]])
                    df[1:].to_csv('media/' + '%s_%s.csv' % (user_pk, file_id), sep='\t', mode = 'a', header = False, index = False)
```

The error says:

> "Process Process-9623:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1506, in _has_valid_type
>       error()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1501, in error
>       axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
>   KeyError: 'the label [9622] is not in the [index]'

In the final result, I get 98 keyerrors in 10,000 lines. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Is lable a column name in your input name?

Comment: No, it is not a column name.